# Visual leak detector unable to start

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, mfc, visual-leak-detector

I am having huge memory leaks in my MFC program which is quite old. Wanted to use visual leak detector to get an idea of the location of the problem. I downloaded and installed VLD v2.4rc2. The include and library paths are automatically added to **VS 2010**. But when i start the application it gives me an error as mentioned below.

```
"The application was unable  to start correctly (0xc0150002). Click OK to close the application."
```

The same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216358/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-after-including-vld-h), and the solution proposed was to copy the files to bin folder of VLD.

**Microsoft.DTfW.DHL.manifest**

**dbghelp.dll**

I cant even find the file Microsoft.DTfW.DHL.manifest anywhere and regarding the dbghelp.dll, I find many location and versions of this file (System32,Programfiles/VS, Syswow64 etc)

I already tried copying all the **dbhhelp.dll** file available. But the situation remains the same. I am using the 64 bit application. Please suggest me how to fix this problem.

Comment: I suspect you are using a manifest declaration for 32 bit and the build platform you are trying to run is 64 bits.