# Visual studio 2010 vld_x86 is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I have application ( not my ) which i try to run from the IDE
the application compiles just fine , but when i try to run it (F5) in debug mode
im getting this link error massage :
[image]

i have window 7 64bit

**UPDATE**
After i installed Visual Leak Detector recompiled and tryed to debug hiting f5
and did as @Michael Stum suggest
now im getting this error :

```
Visual Leak Detector read settings from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\vld.ini
First-chance exception at 0x032374b3 in Kit.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4e52454b.
Unhandled exception at 0x032374b3 in Kit.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4e52454b.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216358/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-after-including-vld-h

Comment: Does your path contain the dll that the dialog mentions?

Comment: i installed the Visual Leak Detector but now it gives me new error see question update 
Thanks!